# Unreadble code Excel 2010 after adding a Shape Hyperlink

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel Report generation functionality on my java application.

I finally managed to add to a picture the Hyperlink without any errors with the following code.

**buildHyperLinksMenu** is the main function that sets the hyperlink

**createHyperLinkWithUri** is a sub function that creates an Uri Hyperlink

```
public void buildHyperLinksMenu(String linkName, XSSFSheet sheet, String tabLinked, String referencedCell) {
    List<XSSFShape> shapes = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getShapes();
    Iterator<XSSFShape> elementsIterator = shapes.iterator();

    while (elementsIterator.hasNext()) {

        XSSFShape shape = elementsIterator.next();
        if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
            CTPicture ctPicture = ((XSSFPicture) shape).getCTPicture();
            CTPictureNonVisual ctpicturenonvisual = ctPicture.getNvPicPr();
            CTNonVisualDrawingProps ctnonvisualdrawingprops = ctpicturenonvisual.getCNvPr();
            String finalname = ctnonvisualdrawingprops.getName();
            //HomeLink is the name of the picture assigned in the sheet to 
            //the image when uploading the Excel template
            if (finalname.equals("HomeLink")) {
                CTHyperlink link = createHyperLinkWithUri(linkName, sheet, tabLinked, referencedCell);
                ((XSSFPicture) shape).getCTPicture().getNvPicPr().getCNvPr().setHlinkClick(link);
            }
        }
    }
}

private CTHyperlink createHyperLinkWithUri(String linkName, XSSFSheet sheet, String tabLinked, String referencedCell) {
    CTHyperlink link = CTHyperlink.Factory.newInstance();
    try {
        String hyperlinkAddress = sheet.getPackagePart().getPartName() + "/#'" + tabLinked + "'!" + referencedCell + "";
        URI uri = new URI(null, null, hyperlinkAddress, null, null);
        sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getPackagePart().addRelationship(uri, TargetMode.INTERNAL, XSSFRelation.SHEET_HYPERLINKS.getRelation());

        String relationshipId = null;
        PackageRelationshipCollection prc = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getPackagePart().getRelationships();
        for (PackageRelationship pr : prc) {
            URI targetURI = pr.getTargetURI();
            String target = targetURI.getPath();
            if (target.equals(hyperlinkAddress)) {
                relationshipId = pr.getId();
                break;
            }
        }

        CTHyperlink hyperlink = CTHyperlink.Factory.newInstance();
        // Set ID of hyperlink to be the same as Relationship ID
        hyperlink.setId(relationshipId);
        return hyperlink;
    } catch (URISyntaxException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        return link;
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that after generation the excel (when opened) will prompt the "unreadable content" message and no hyperlink is added.

I'd like to understand if it's an issue of the piece of code i posted that i'm missing or is something more annoying like versions of libraries etc..

I confirm that the `if (finalname.equals("HomeLink"))` is satisfied one and only one time.

Here's is the simple function called to write the file in the output:

```
protected byte[] workbookToByteArray(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Davide

**UDPATE**

I generated an Excel document with and without the functionality of adding the HyperLink (the code above basically).

The corrupted Excel says that file xl\drawings\drawing4.xml is the one corrupted.
So i took the two excels, unzipped them and compared the xml files. The only differences between those two are:

Correct file

```
<a:blip xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" r:embed="rId2">
```

vs

Wrong file

```
<a:blip r:embed="rId2">
```

This difference happens many time in this similar way. Many other

**UDPATE**

Seems like that the line that is creating the issue is when adding the relation to the package

```
    sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getPackagePart().addRelationship(uri, TargetMode.INTERNAL, XSSFRelation.SHEET_HYPERLINKS.getRelation());
```

**SOLUTION CODE**

```
public void buildHyperLinksMenu(String linkName, XSSFSheet sheet, String tabLinked, String referencedCell) {
    List<XSSFShape> shapes = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getShapes();
    Iterator<XSSFShape> elementsIterator = shapes.iterator();

while (elementsIterator.hasNext()) {

    XSSFShape shape = elementsIterator.next();
    if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
        CTPicture ctPicture = ((XSSFPicture) shape).getCTPicture();
        CTPictureNonVisual ctpicturenonvisual = ctPicture.getNvPicPr();
        CTNonVisualDrawingProps ctnonvisualdrawingprops = ctpicturenonvisual.getCNvPr();                 
        String finalname = ctnonvisualdrawingprops.getName();
        if (finalname.equals("HomeLink")) {
            CTHyperlink link = createHyperLinkWithUri(linkName, sheet, tabLinked, referencedCell);
            ((XSSFPicture) shape).getCTPicture().getNvPicPr().getCNvPr().setHlinkClick(link);


        }
    }
}
```

}

```
private CTHyperlink createHyperLinkWithUri(String linkName, XSSFSheet sheet, String tabLinked, String referencedCell) {
    CTHyperlink link = CTHyperlink.Factory.newInstance();
    try {
        CTHyperlink hyperlink = CTHyperlink.Factory.newInstance();
        String hyperlinkAddress = "#'" + tabLinked + "'!" + referencedCell + "";
        sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship(hyperlinkAddress, PackageRelationshipTypes.HYPERLINK_PART);

        String relationshipId = null;
        PackageRelationshipCollection prc = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getPackagePart().getRelationships();
        for (PackageRelationship pr : prc) {
            String targetURI = pr.getTargetURI().toString();
            if (targetURI.equals(hyperlinkAddress)) {
                relationshipId = pr.getId();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Set ID of hyperlink to be the same as Relationship ID
        hyperlink.setId(relationshipId);
        return hyperlink;
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        return link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try whether https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141061/apache-poi-putting-hyperlink-in-images/48155270#48155270 works for you. This is a complete example which creates Excel workbook having two pictures with hyperlinks in Sheet1. One of the hyperlinks is a link to "#Sheet2!B3". Just tested, works using `apache poi 4.0.1` too. The problem in your code is the URI you are creating. The target in `/xl/drawings/_rels/drawing1.xml.rels` should only be `Target="#Sheet2!B3" ` without the part name.

Comment: Man you are a damn genius. You saved my life. Thanks

Comment: May i ask you also for an issue with spaces in the URL. For example a table is called "Table First". If i leave the normal space when adding the uri it gives me syntax error. If i add to the string %20 it goes correct but in the excel it keeps %20 in the hyperlink and he does not find Table%20First

Comment: The target in `/xl/drawings/_rels/drawing1.xml.rels` should be `Target="#'Table First'!B3"` then. So the sheet name containing a space in single qoutes. So `setHyperlinkToPicture(picture, "#'Table First'!B3");` in my code. Not tested yet, but should work.

Comment: Ok fixed, should have worked with URI and his path.

Comment: Thanks for your time sir