# Add hyperlink to org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTextBox in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to add a hyperlink(referring to the same document with a different sheet say E1) using Textbox. The hyperlink is created in this But this is not referring to Sheet E1.

Below is my code.

```
    XSSFSheet sheet = templateWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
    XSSFTextBox textBox = drawing.createTextbox(anchor);
    textBox.setFillColor(112, 80, 151);
    textBox.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    XSSFRichTextString text = new XSSFRichTextString("text");
     
     textBox.setTopInset(0.25D);
   
     textBox.setText("text");
     CTTextCharacterProperties rpr = textBox.getCTShape().getTxBody().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr();
     Color color = Color.white;
     rpr.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)color.getRed(),(byte)color.getGreen(),(byte)color.getBlue()});
    CTHyperlink hyperlink = CTHyperlink.Factory.newInstance();
    

    
    textBox.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setHlinkClick(hyperlink);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Apache poi putting hyperlink in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141061/apache-poi-putting-hyperlink-in-images/48155270#48155270) for the same problem with pictures.

The hyperlink target is not set in `CTHyperlink` directly. Instead the `CTHyperlink` refers to a reference in package relationship of the drawing. The package relationship then refers to the hyperlink target.  So the need is creating that package relationship and set its id to the `CTHyperlink`.

Complete example tested and works using current `apache poi 5.0.0`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTShape;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTShapeNonVisual;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTNonVisualDrawingProps;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationship;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipTypes;


public class CreateExcelTextBoxHyperlink {
    
 private static void setHyperlinkToShape(XSSFSimpleShape shape, String hyperlinkurl) throws Exception {

  XSSFDrawing drawing = shape.getDrawing();
  PackageRelationship packagerelationship = 
    drawing.getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship(hyperlinkurl, PackageRelationshipTypes.HYPERLINK_PART);
  String rid = packagerelationship.getId();

  CTShape ctshape = shape.getCTShape();
  CTShapeNonVisual crshapenonvisual = ctshape.getNvSpPr();
  if (crshapenonvisual == null) crshapenonvisual = ctshape.addNewNvSpPr();
  CTNonVisualDrawingProps ctnonvisualdrawingprops = crshapenonvisual.getCNvPr();
  if (ctnonvisualdrawingprops == null) ctnonvisualdrawingprops = crshapenonvisual.addNewCNvPr();
  CTHyperlink cthyperlink = ctnonvisualdrawingprops.getHlinkClick();
  if (cthyperlink == null) cthyperlink = ctnonvisualdrawingprops.addNewHlinkClick();
  cthyperlink.setId(rid);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx"));

  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  XSSFClientAnchor anchor =  drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3);
  anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
  XSSFTextBox textBox = drawing.createTextbox(anchor);
  textBox.setFillColor(112, 80, 151);
  textBox.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
  textBox.setTopInset(0.25D);
  
  XSSFRichTextString text = workbook.getCreationHelper().createRichTextString("text");
  XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
  font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex()); 
  text.applyFont(font);
  textBox.setText(text);
  
  setHyperlinkToShape(textBox, "#Sheet2!E1");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelNew.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

The hyperlink target `URI` `#Sheet2!E1` refers to cell `E1` in sheet named `Sheet2`.

Since `apache poi` takes all hyperlink targets as `URI`s which need to be `URI` encoded, target sheet names must not contain spaces. If the target sheet name would be `Sheet 2`, then the target `URI` wouldmust be `#'Sheet%202'!E1`. But `Excel` expects `#'Sheet 2'!E1`. So for `Excel` those targets are not `URI`s at all. But for `apache poi` they are.

Comment: In my case hyperlink contains spaces also. how will I make hyperlink in that case. (like Sheet 2)

Comment: @Neeraj Agarwal: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251131/excel-hyperlinks-uri-fragment-not-encoding/61253650#61253650: I cannot see any way to produce that wrong URI using apache poi.