# How to add Vertical Line to a Bar Chart using POI 4.0.1 Java

Tags: excel, charts, apache-poi

How do you add vertical line to a bar chart(horizontal) using POI. I am trying to add a line similar to this orange vertical line.
[Bar chart + vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N090D.png)

Referred here for manual MS Excel working
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2344-excel-add-vertical-line-to-bar-chart.html

I have referred this answer for combining column chart with a horizontal line chart
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080178/9693259

To create this graph
[Column chart + horizontal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR2iR.png)

I have changed the column chart to be a bar chart
[Bar chart + horizontal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfLKN.png)

But I cannot find how to change the orientation of the line chart like I did with the column to bar.
Bar chart has category axis on left, value axis on bottom.
Line chart only accepts category axis on bottom.

Edit:
[Attempt at Bar chart + Line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHxXK.png)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong with my answer? It is not very polite simply not to react anymore when somebody tries helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read your linked [How to add vertical/average line to bar chart in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2344-excel-add-vertical-line-to-bar-chart.html) correct, then you will see, that there is bar chart and scatter chart combined and not bar chart and line chart. This is because the average value must be on X axis of the chart and only scatter chart is able displaying decimal values on X axis. For all other charts, the X axis is a category axis.

So to create the same as in the linked article using `apache poi` we can do it like this using the low level underlying ooxml beans (`ooxml-schemas-*.jar` must be in class path):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*;

public class BarAndScatterChartLowLevel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

  Row row;
  Cell cell;

  row = sheet.createRow(0);
  row.createCell(0);
  row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Bars");

  for (int r = 1; r < 7; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("C" + r);
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellFormula("RANDBETWEEN(5, 10)/10");
  }

  row = sheet.createRow(7);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Average");
  row = sheet.createRow(8);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Y");
  row.createCell(1).setCellValue("X");
  row = sheet.createRow(9);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue(0);
  row.createCell(1).setCellFormula("AVERAGE($B$2:$B$7)");
  row = sheet.createRow(10);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue(1);
  row.createCell(1).setCellFormula("AVERAGE($B$2:$B$7)");

  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 11, 15);

  XSSFChart chart = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).createChart(anchor);

  CTChart ctChart = chart.getCTChart();  
  CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();

  //the bar chart
  CTBarChart ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
  CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
  ctBoolean.setVal(true);
  ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.BAR);

  //the bar series
  CTBarSer ctBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
  CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctBarSer.addNewTx();
  CTStrRef ctStrRef = ctSerTx.addNewStrRef();
  ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$1");
  ctBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(0);  
  CTAxDataSource cttAxDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewCat();
  ctStrRef = cttAxDataSource.addNewStrRef();
  ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7"); 
  CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewVal();
  CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
  ctNumRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7");

  //telling the BarChart that it has axes and giving them Ids
  ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //cat axis 1 (bars)
  ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //val axis 1 (left)

  //the scatter chart
  CTScatterChart ctScatterChart = ctPlotArea.addNewScatterChart();
  ctBoolean = ctScatterChart.addNewVaryColors();
  ctBoolean.setVal(true);

  //the scatter series
  CTScatterSer ctScatterSer = ctScatterChart.addNewSer();
  ctSerTx = ctScatterSer.addNewTx();
  ctStrRef = ctSerTx.addNewStrRef();
  ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$8");
  ctScatterSer.addNewIdx().setVal(1);  
  cttAxDataSource = ctScatterSer.addNewXVal();
  ctStrRef = cttAxDataSource.addNewStrRef();
  ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$10:$B$11"); 
  ctNumDataSource = ctScatterSer.addNewYVal();
  ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
  ctNumRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$10:$A$11");

  //telling the ScatterChart that it has axes and giving them Ids
  ctScatterChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123458); //cat axis 2 (scatter)
  ctScatterChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123459); //val axis 2 (right)

  //cat axis 1 (bars)
  CTCatAx ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx(); 
  ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
  CTScaling ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
  ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
  ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
  ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
  ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
  ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

  //val axis 1 (left)
  CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx(); 
  ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
  ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
  ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
  ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
  ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
  ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
  ctValAx.addNewCrosses().setVal(STCrosses.AUTO_ZERO); //this val axis crosses the cat axis at zero
  ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

  //cat axis 2 (scatter)
  ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx(); 
  ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123458); //id of the cat axis
  ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
  ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
  ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(true); //this cat axis is deleted
  ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
  ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123459); //id of the val axis
  ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

  //val axis 2 (right)
  ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx(); 
  ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123459); //id of the val axis
  ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
  ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
  ctScaling.addNewMax().setVal(1.0);
  ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
  ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.R);
  ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123458); //id of the cat axis
  ctValAx.addNewCrosses().setVal(STCrosses.MAX); //this val axis crosses the cat axis at max value
  ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

  //legend
  CTLegend ctLegend = ctChart.addNewLegend();
  ctLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.B);
  ctLegend.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("BarAndScatterChart.xlsx");
  wb.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

But since `apache poi 4.0.1` provides the `XDDF` stuff now, the same could be done as follows:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

public class BarAndScatterChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
   // Create the data
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

   Row row;
   Cell cell;

   row = sheet.createRow(0);
   row.createCell(0);
   row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Bars");

   for (int r = 1; r < 7; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r);
    cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("C" + r);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellFormula("RANDBETWEEN(5, 10)/10");
   }

   row = sheet.createRow(7);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Average");
   row = sheet.createRow(8);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Y");
   row.createCell(1).setCellValue("X");
   row = sheet.createRow(9);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue(0);
   row.createCell(1).setCellFormula("AVERAGE($B$2:$B$7)");
   row = sheet.createRow(10);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue(1);
   row.createCell(1).setCellFormula("AVERAGE($B$2:$B$7)");

   // create data sources
   XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 6, 0, 0));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> barVal = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 6, 1, 1));
   XDDFDataSource<Double> scatterX = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(9, 10, 1, 1));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> scatterY = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(9, 10, 0, 0));

   XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 11, 15);

   XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
   XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
   legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);

   // bar chart

   // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
   XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

   XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
   XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(cat, barVal);
   series1.setTitle("bars", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, 1, true, true));
   chart.plot(data);

   // in order to transform a bar chart into a column chart, you just need to change the bar direction
   XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
   bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);

   solidFillSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.CHARTREUSE);

   // scatter chart

   // axis must be there but must not be visible
   bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   bottomAxis.setVisible(false);
   // right axis for scatter chart
   XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
   rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);
   rightAxis.setMaximum(1.0);

   // set correct cross axis
   bottomAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
   rightAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

   data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.SCATTER, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
   XDDFScatterChartData.Series series2 = (XDDFScatterChartData.Series)data.addSeries(scatterX, scatterY);
   series2.setTitle("average", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 7, 0, true, true));
   series2.setSmooth(false); 
   chart.plot(data);

   // correct the id and order, must not be 0 again because there is one bar series already
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);

   solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-bar-and-scatter-chart.xlsx")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }

 private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setFillProperties(fill);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }

 private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
  line.setFillProperties(fill);
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setLineProperties(line);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer opened a new perspective to look at the problem. I was referring an article of Bar+Scatter in Excel, but when I actually took to my attempts I ended up doing Bar+Line all the time. I couldn't think where I had gone wrong. The Bar+Line approach worked for the vertical bar case only because the Line uses X-axis as categorical and Y as numerical. And with vertical bars using the same X-cat, Y-num there was no conflict. But then we shifted Bar to X-num, Y-cat, whereas Line still refers to X-cat, Y-num and my attempts were focused at trying to map X multiple times.

Comment: What I was doing wrong resulted similar to the pic in Edit. I tried to map same X-cat value against what I assumed was the fixed Y-num range of the graph which resulted in a sloped straight line. It has by now become clear to me that the chart handles categorical level in the order as they appear in the series rather than checking lexicographically, which was a wrong assumption to make. Experimenting with merging the cells in the data source has also shown that merging leaves undesirable results in the graph.